# jQuery tooltip detect screen edge

Tags: jquery, edge-detection

I have some basic hover/tooltip code working that needs to be modified so that a second class name is added when the tooltip hits the edge of the browser window. Can anyone lend a hand?

```
this.tooltip = function () {
    $(".challenge_card").hover(function (e) {
                $(this).parent().append("<div id='tooltip'></div>");
                $("#tooltip")
                        .fadeIn("fast");
            },
            function () {
                $("#tooltip").remove();
            });
};
```

Comment: @ahren here's how I have the code setup. '
        $(".challenge_card").hover(function (e) {
                    $(this).parent().append("<div id='tooltip'></div>");
$("#tooltip").fadeIn("fast");
                    if ($tooltip.offset().left + $tooltip.outerWidth() > wW) {
                        alert($(window).width());
                    }
                },
                function () {
                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                });
    };
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        tooltip();'

Answer (score 4):

```
var wW = $(window).width();
var $tooltip = $('#tooltip');

if($tooltip.offset().left + $tooltip.outerWidth() > wW){
  // You've hit the right side of the browser window
}
```

Something like this should work - doesn't take into account the top position of course, but gives you the basic logic to check the position of the tooltip...

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting your solution to work. The only way to prevent an error is placing the if statement within the .hover function. Nothing happens when the tooltip hits the right side of the window.

Comment: what's the error you get? I didn't write anything to reposition it, you just wanted to know how to detect the screen edge...

Comment: "Cannot read property 'left' of null" is the error. I was testing with a simple alert.

Comment: `$tooltip` has to exist, and be visible to have an offset... or rather, not `display:none;`

Comment: I'll reply in a new comment. It's getting hard to share in this thread.