# How can I move an absolute positioned element if out of viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many boxes with differents widths. All of them are displayed `inline-block` so they will be distributed  differently as window width changes.

Every box has a big tooltip that will show on hover. These tooltips have a fixed width and height, same for all of the boxes.

These tooltips are `position:absolute` over the boxes and centered with:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -halfwidth;
```

My problem is that if the box is close to window left or right they will be partially hidden (I have no problem with top and bottom, they will never reach those edges)

Is there any easy way with javascript (better if jquery) to detect when the element is out of the viewport and then change the `left` property accordingly to prevent it?

any help, hint or comment will be greatly apreciated. Thank You

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/8dc18sLb/)

```css
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
ul {
  width:100%; 
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  padding:0;
  }
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -175px;
  bottom:25px;
  display: none;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

li:hover .hover-element {
  display: block;
}
.hover-element:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you use left:0 so that it will always display?

Comment: Because the designer want, when possible, centered. It will have a comic baloon aspect. but even if left:0, I will have the same problem but just at the right side of the window

Comment: This question might help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461096/jquery-tooltip-detect-screen-edge

Comment: Ty. checking it out

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez i made the snippet below, please check, thats all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look:

```js
var windowWidth = document.body.scrollWidth || window.innerWidth;
$('li').on('mouseenter', function(e){
  var $hover = $(this).find('.hover-element');
  var coords = $hover[0] && $hover[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  var rightDistance = 0;
  
  if (coords.left <= 0) {
    $hover.css({
      'left': ($hover.css('left').split('px')[0] - coords.left) + 'px'
    })
  }
  rightDistance = windowWidth - coords.left - $hover.width() - 2 * $hover.css('borderWidth').split('px')[0];
  if (rightDistance < 0) {
    $hover.css({
      'left': ($hover.css('left').split('px')[0] - (-rightDistance)) + 'px'
    })
  }
  $('p').html($hover.css('left') + '/' + coords.left)
})
```

```css
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;overflow-x: hidden;}
ul {
  width:100%; 
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  padding:0;
  }
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -175px;
  bottom:25px;
  display: none;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

li:hover .hover-element {
  display: block;
}
.hover-element:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome. Ty so much. that was I was hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Thats all you need, i detected the offset left position of the div, and added the class to `li` and a small tweaks in css.

```js
$("li").mouseenter(function(){
 var f = $(this).find('.hover-element');
    var rightEdge = f.width() + f.offset().left;
    var leftEdge = f.offset().left;
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    if(leftEdge < 0){
    $(this).addClass("left");
    $(this).removeClass("right");
    }
    else if(rightEdge > screenWidth){
    $(this).addClass("right");
    $(this).removeClass("left");
    }
    else{
    $(this).removeClass("right lefft");
    }


});

$("li").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).removeClass("right lefft");
})
```

```css
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
ul {
  width:100%; 
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  padding:0;
  }
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -175px;
  bottom:25px;
  display: none;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
li.left .hover-element{
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
li.right .hover-element{
    margin-left: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
li:hover .hover-element {
  display: block;
}
.hover-element:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ty for your answer. It's correct. I upvote your answer but I have to give credit to JiangangXiong as his answer works better as it move the tooltip as I was whising, just enough right or left to avoid beign hidden. Anyway ty so much

Answer (score 1):

The following links are a starting point for your question (if not the actual answer).

> Is there any easy way with javascript (better if jquery) to detect when the element is out of the viewport and then change the left property accordingly to prevent it?

[How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433)

[Absolute position of an element on the screen using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929972/absolute-position-of-an-element-on-the-screen-using-jquery)

Comment: Ty, will check those links

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to mention the steps here. If you'd need the code, just ask for it. I am currently on my mobile device, so typing the code would get hard!

## Steps

- To make things easy to include JS, change the display property using JS. Accomplish this using a mouse event on each of the list items, that changes their respective tooltip's display property. ([Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) how to access the respective child)

In the same hover event, do these:

- After changing the display, check if the tooltip element is in viewport. You can refer to the link Victor Medeiros provided.
- If is not completely in viewport, <strike>change the margin-left property to `-175px - (the number of pixels it crossed the boundary by)`.</strike> I just realised, if it crosses the viewport, just set the margin-left or margin-right (as applicable, find it by getBoundingClientRect) to 0.

Yep, that's it! I hope that should work, I haven't tried it out. What's the result?

Comment: ty for your time. JiangangXiong gave me the right code :)

Answer (score -5):

Change

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Whit

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: static;
}
```